# TeamCity- Removing command line parameter that is added automatically?

Tags: java, linux, gradle, continuous-integration, teamcity

Within `TeamCity`, how can I *remove* a command line parameter that is passed automatically before I declare my own arguments?

Within my `gradle` TeamCity build the `--init-script` argument is being added automatically by TeamCity to a pre-set value.

I would like to *remove* this? How do I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--init-script` is added by TeamCity Gradle Runner type. It is essential for TeamCity-Gradle integration and can not be removed, unless another type of runner is used (e.g., Command Line Runner).

In case you need to add more init scripts, feel free to add yours using `--init-script <path>` in "*Additional Gradle command line parameters*" field. Gradle supports multiple init scripts.